# What we mean when we say that a class is loaded?

Tags: classloader

That is :
What is actually loaded. The logic or the class file or some metadata related to the file.

Answer (score 0):

It would usually mean that the logic and properties of a class have loaded, but depending on the context, it could mean other things too.

Answer (score 0):

From a class loader implementation perspective, class loading has completed when calling ClassLoader.defineClass(...). I.e. when the class is made known to the JVM.